# How can I remove rows with unique values, keeping rows with duplicate values?

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet of surveys, in which I need to see how particular users have varied over time. As such, I need to disregard all rows with unique values in a particular column. The data looks like this:

```
Response Date           Response_ID Account_ID  Q.1
10/20/2011 12:03:43 PM  23655956    1168161     8
10/20/2011 03:52:57 PM  23660161    1168152     0
10/21/2011 10:55:54 AM  23672903    1166121     7
10/23/2011 04:28:16 PM  23694471    1144756     9
10/25/2011 06:30:52 AM  23732674    1167449     7
10/25/2011 07:52:28 AM  23734597    1087618     5
```

I've found a way to do so in Excel VBA:

```vba
Sub Del_Unique()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Columns("A:A").Copy Destination:=Columns("B:B")
    i = Application.CountIf(Range("A:A"), "<>") + 50
    If i > 65536 Then i = 65536
    Do
        If Application.CountIf(Range("B:B"), Range("A" & i)) = 1 Then
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
        i = i - 1
    Loop Until i = 0
    Columns("B:B").Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I'd like to do it in Google Spreadsheets with a script that won't have to be changed. Closest I can get is retrieving all duplicate user ids from the range, but can't associate that with the row. That code follows:

```
function findDuplicatesInSelection() {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var values = activeRange.getValues();

  // values that appear at least once
  var once = {};

  // values that appear at least twice
  var twice = {};

  // values that appear at least twice, stored in a pretty fashion!
  var final = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
     var inner = values[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < inner.length; j++) {
      var cell = inner[j];
      if (cell == "") continue;
      if (once.hasOwnProperty(cell)) {
        if (!twice.hasOwnProperty(cell)) {
          final.push(cell);
        }
        twice[cell] = 1;
      } else {
        once[cell] = 1;
      }
    }
  }

  if (final.length == 0) {
    Browser.msgBox("No duplicates found");
  } else {
    Browser.msgBox("Duplicates are: " + final);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I caught that in the tag, and forgot I typed it in the title. Like I said, new to this stuff.

Comment: I'm not sure a mis-tagged question warrant a vote-down.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe not very efficient, but I think it's what you want:

```
var ar=[1,3,3,5,6,8,6,6];

console.log("Before:");
display(ar);//1 3 3 5 6 8 6 6
var index=[];
var ar2=[];
for(var a=0;a<ar.length;a++)
{
    var duplicate=false;
    for(var b=0;b<ar.length;b++)
    {
        if(ar[a]==ar[b]&&a!=b)
        {
            duplicate=true;
        }
    }
    if(!duplicate)
    {
        index.push(a);
    }
}
for(var a=0;a<index.length;a++)
{
    ar[index[a]]=null;
}
for(var a=0;a<ar.length;a++)
{
    if(ar[a]!=null)ar2.push(ar[a]);
}
console.log("After:");
display(ar2);//3 3 6 6 6

function display(x)
{
    for(var a=0;a<x.length;a++)console.log(x[a]);
}
```

The fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mageek/6AGQ4/

And a shorter version that is as a function :

```
var ar=[1,3,3,5,6,8,6,6];

function removeUnique(x)
{
    var index=[];
    var ar2=[];
    for(var a=0;a<ar.length;a++)
    {
        var duplicate=0;
        for(var b=0;b<ar.length;b++)if(ar[a]==ar[b]&&a!=b)duplicate=1;
        if(!duplicate)index.push(a);
    }
    for(var a=0;a<index.length;a++)ar[index[a]]=null;
    for(var a=0;a<ar.length;a++)if(ar[a]!=null)ar2.push(ar[a]);
    return x;
}

ar=removeUnique(ar);
```

The fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mageek/6AGQ4/2

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest going for something simple.

1. Create a short script that flags duplicates
2. Write the formula directly into the cell "=flagDuplicate(C2,C$2:C$10)"
3. Copy the forumla down the column
4. Use Spreadsheet's built in QUERY formula to pull the information you need
   "=QUERY(A1:E10; "SELECT * WHERE E = TRUE"; 1)"

Here is a simple function to flag duplicates

```
function flagDuplicate(value, array) {
  var duplicateCounter = 0;

   for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
     if (array[i] == value){           // I avoid === in Spreadsheet functions
       duplicateCounter++;
      }
   }

   if (duplicateCounter > 1){
     return true;
   }else{
     return false;
   }
}
```

Too many functions on a large table can slow things down.  If it becomes a problem, you can always copy and "paste values only" - that will retain the information but remove the functions.

Best of luck.

*Note:  When I tested this I noticed that can take a while before the spreadsheet recognizes the new custom function (gives error like can't find function FLAGDUPLICATE)*

Comment: Excellent! I didn't even realize you could call custom functions like that! I love learning this kind of jibber jab.

Comment: Hm, I'm running into an issue after running the function a couple of times. It gets stuck thinking and times out. I'm dealing with just under 2k cells, which is well under spreadsheets limits, but it still seems to be a big operation. Is there a way to stream line it, you think?

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it using arrays to handle the whole sheet at once :

```
function removeUnique(){
  var col = 2 ; // choose the column you want to check for unique elements
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data=ss.getDataRange().getValues();// get all data
    data.sort(function(x,y){
//  var xp = Number(x[col]);// use these to sort on numeric values
//  var yp = Number(y[col]);
  var xp = x[col];// use these for non-numeric values
  var yp = y[col];
  Logger.log(xp+'   '+yp); // just to check the sort is OK
  return xp == yp ? 0 : xp < yp ? -1 : 1;// sort on column col numeric ascending
});
  var cc=0;
  var newdata = new Array();
  for(nn=0;nn<data.length-1;++nn){
    if(data[nn+1][col]==data[nn][col]||cc>0){
    newdata.push(data[nn]);
    ++cc;
    if(cc>1){cc=0}}
    }
  ss.getDataRange().clearContent();  // clear the sheet
  sh.getRange(1,1,newdata.length,newdata[0].length).setValues(newdata);// paste new values sorted and without unique elements
  }
```

EDIT : here is the version that keeps all duplicates (the working one)

```
function removeUnique(){
  var col = 2 ; // choose the column you want to check for unique elements
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data=ss.getDataRange().getValues();// get all data
    data.sort(function(x,y){
//  var xp = Number(x[col]);// use these to sort on numeric values
//  var yp = Number(y[col]);
  var xp = x[col];// use these for non-numeric values
  var yp = y[col];
  Logger.log(xp+'   '+yp); // just to check the sort is OK
  return xp == yp ? 0 : xp < yp ? -1 : 1;// sort on column col numeric ascending
});
  var newdata = new Array();
  for(nn=0;nn<data.length-1;++nn){
    if(data[nn+1][col]==data[nn][col]){
    newdata.push(data[nn]);
    }
    }
    if(data[nn-1][col]==data[nn][col]){newdata.push(data[nn])}
  ss.getDataRange().clearContent();  // clear the sheet
  sh.getRange(1,1,newdata.length,newdata[0].length).setValues(newdata);// paste new values sorted and without unique elements
  }
```

Comment: Hm, I like this. Only problem is it only takes one duplicate, not if there's more than one. Is there a way to make it pull all rows with duplicate IDs?

Comment: this one is ok, maybe not the most elegant but working nicely ;-)